# Apache Hive how to identify which column is the partition

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-partitioning

I have a set of log files, created a Hive table, now i want to partition the table based on a col what I don't understand & have not seen examples is how to specify the column for partition how to specify the col/field
Ex. here is line from the log

2012-04-11 16:49:10,629 ~ [http-7001-11] ~DE1F6F6667913022AE2620D1228817D6 ~  END  ~ /admin/bp/setup/newedit/ok   ~ pt ~ 219 ~

table struc is
CREATE TABLE log (starttime STRING, thread STRING,   session STRING,  method STRING, targeturl STRING, registry string,  ipaddress STRING, details STRING) ROW FORMAT  DELIMITED   FIELDS TERMINATED BY '~';
Now if I want the 6the col i.e. **'registry'** to be the partition for the logs , how would I write the partition statement.
**In general if I have a line (row) with cols c1,c2,..... c10
how to specify col ci in the partition?**
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do first is to explicitely tell which columns you expect to be partitions as you create your table. To make `registry` your partition:

```
CREATE TABLE log(starttime STRING, thread STRING, session STRING, method STRING, targeturl STRING, ipaddress STRING, details STRING)
PARTITIONED BY (registry STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '~'
```

You can add as many partitions as you want, each partition will be a nested sub-folder, and the order in which you declare your partitions in the `PARTITIONED BY` matters: the first one will be the top-level partition, the second one will be 1 level down, ... An example:

```
|--- mytable
      `---- mypartition1=x
                   `-------- mypartition2=x
                                     `------- ...
```

What I would do is:

1. Create an external table pointing to the location of your log directory, with no partitions at all (just contains the raw log file), which will populate the table `raw_log` with all your data, with no partition (yet):

   ```
   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE raw_log(starttime STRING, thread STRING, session STRING, method STRING, targeturl STRING, registry STRING, ipaddress STRING, details STRING)
   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '~'
   LOCATION '/path/to/your/log/dir'
   ```
2. Use Hive's dynamic partitions feature to read from `raw_log` and insert into `log`:

   ```
   FROM raw_log raw
   INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE log PARTITION(registry)
          SELECT raw.starttime, raw.thread, raw.session, raw.method, raw.targeturl, raw.ipaddress, raw.details
   ```

You can read more on dynamic partitions [on the official Apache wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial#Tutorial-DynamicpartitionInsert)

Comment: I like your solution,  will do it that way,I understood your solution,Thanks!. But just for understanding, If I don't create raw_log, how does one tell hive if I have a row of data having cols c1,c2,c3...c10 (i.e. sep by ex. ~) how does one specify col c3 or c5 as the partition col?

Comment: You do that in your dynamic partition query. In 
`INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE log PARTITION(registry)`, you are specifying that in your partitioned log table you would like registry to serve as the partition column. 
If you had multiple partition levels, you would do PARTITION(c3, c5) instead.

Comment: @Integration Sorry for the delay, yes what Mark said is exactly right, you specify your partitions in the **PARTITION** statement.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, hive has had an issue with external tables that are partitioned.  Say that you create your table declaring it external, after you setup your data in subdirectories of the form, for instance, dt=21012-04-01, and other similar directories.  All appears fine except that your data will not show in selects.

Elastic map reduce added a feature that solves this problem

```
ALTER TABLE log RECOVER PARTITIONS;
```

I am adding this info since it took me a while to find out why my data was not there.